# Дополнительная обработка формы в Symfony, UVdesk

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

Я развернул данный сервис поддержки клиентов (https://github.com/uvdesk/community-skeleton#documentation).

Вот форма подачи обращения авторизованного пользователя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно сделать следующее: при определенном типе обращения проверить на ошибки прикрепленные файлы, если ошибок нет - разрешить создание обращения, если ошибки есть - сообщить об этом и не дать создать обращение.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я должен это сделать? Направьте, может есть аналогичные примеры?

Comment: Поищите в документации что то вида "валидация формы". Может есть возможность повесить внешний обработчик...

Comment: @swad в доках такого нет. там вообще нет тех документации... разработчик предложил работать со следующим файлом: your-project/vendor/uvdesk/core-framework/Resources/views/Templates/attachment.html.twig